# Why does @GrailsCompileStatic allow calling dynamic GORM finders but not domainClass.withTransaction()?

Tags: grails, annotations, grails-2.5

Adding the *@GrailsCompileStatic* annotation to a method or class allows the usage of dynamic GORM finders, e.g. *findAllByIdAndProperty()*.
However, adding the annotation does not allow for *domainClass.withTransaction()*, which is also a GORM AST addition. Why?

(Using grails-2.5.3)

**UPDATE (05/10/16 - 10:25AM)**
@jeff-scott-brown is right, it does work in general, so here is the code that fails with *@GrailsCompileStatic*:

```
...
RestfulApiService service = ServiceUtils.getService(resourceName)
service.resourceClass.withTransaction { /* do something */ }
```

(*resourceClass* is of type Class)

The error:

```
Compilation error: startup failed:
C:\...\myfile.groovy: 100: [Static type checking] - Cannot find matching method java.lang.Class#withTransaction(groovy.lang.Closure). Please check if the declared type is right and if the method exists.
@ line 100, column 13.
           service.resourceClass.withTransaction {
           ^
```

Why does *withTransaction()* fail in this case once the annotation is added?

Comment: Are you passing a closure to `withTransaction`? I don't believe a no-arg static method exists.

Comment: @dpcasady I think the asker abbreviated `withTransaction()` for the same reason he/she abbreviated `findAllByIdAndProperty()`.  Calling `withTransaction()` would be nonsensical.

Comment: @dpcasady It's abbreviated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does @GrailsCompileStatic allow calling dynamic GORM finders but
>   not domainClass.withTransaction()?

It does.  The code at https://github.com/jeffbrown/withtx/blob/master/grails-app/controllers/demo/DemoController.groovy compiles.

```
import grails.compiler.GrailsCompileStatic

@GrailsCompileStatic
class DemoController {

    def index() {
        Person.withTransaction {
            // ...
        }
        render 'Success!'
    }
}
```

Comment: The reasons that dynamic finders are allowed are not the same reasons that `withTransaction` is allowed.  `withTransaction` is allowed because it can be statically verified.  The reason dynamic finders are allowed is that we have a type checking extension that knows about dynamic finder calls and will turn those into dynamically dispatched in a class where everything else is being statically dispatched.

Comment: Ok I see - but why does `withTransaction()` fail in my case? I've added the failing code to the original post.

Comment: Because the compiler can't verify that `service.resourceClass` is a domain class.

Comment: You can't invoke `withTransaction` on any `Class`.  The reference has to point to a domain class in particular and the compile has to be able to guarantee that.  That is the point of static type checking.  If the return type of your `getResourceClass` method is `java.lang.Class`, then that would be problematic for the static type checker.

Comment: had this issue after upgrading my java from java 1.8 to java 1.11. it's really frustrating because I had to remove the @GrailsCompileStatic from some sensitive classes to prevent the error